# Missing full stop in privileges area

Tags: bug, status-completed

I have just noticed that there is a missing full stop at the end of [this sentence](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) (the last one):

[image]

And as it is really bugging me (because I am a Grammar Nazi), I thought that I would report it.

Comment: A grammar Nazi?  Making a spelling error in the title???  **:D :D :D**

Comment: @Fabby: Grammar is not the same as spelling... **:P**

Comment: I know!  It's still funny as hell!  **>:-)**

Comment: Report this on [meta.se]. It's SE-wide.

Comment: @muru: Ok, I have done so [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266615/missing-full-stop-in-privileges-area). :)

Comment: Well the problem seems to be fixed now...

Comment: @Daniel: I have posted an answer to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also reported this on Meta SE, and as this issue was of the highest priority they immediately fixed it as stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266664/280862). **;-)**